# Cannot run assets:precompile due to initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to precompile assets to a production environment with RoR 6.X.X.
in `config/initializers`, I have an initializer that connects to a third-party service API. When I execute `bundle exec rails assets:precompile` it crashes because the API key is not defined yet for that initialiser (and I don't need the initializer to build CSS and JS...). Few releases ago, the config property `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` was alive but now it doesn't exist anymore.

How Am I supposed to build my assets now?